# How to convert to 1-dimensional list a list of a string that is list that contains int elements

Tags: python, list

Can't figure out how to make a proper 1-dimensional list out of

```
a = ['[2,5911,3391,10687,9796,15870,11533]']
a[1:-1]
```

i want to get
[2,5911,3391,10687,9796,15870,11533]

Slices don't seem to work there

Is there any elegant way to do it without writing 2 for loops
Appreciate all the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first get the string `a[0]` then remove the brakets: `a[0][1:-1]` then you can use `.split()` like so:

```
a = ['[2,5911,3391,10687,9796,15870,11533]']
a = a[0][1:-1].split(',')
print(a)
```

Output:

```
['2', '5911', '3391', '10687', '9796', '15870', '11533']
```

You can also get the integers (if that's what you're after) using a list comprehension like so:

```
a = ['[2,5911,3391,10687,9796,15870,11533]']
a = [int(item) for item in a[0][1:-1].split(',')]
print(a)
```

Output:

```
[2, 5911, 3391, 10687, 9796, 15870, 11533]
```

Comment: I am an idiot) Thank u so so much)

Comment: @bigsbi I glad it helped! If this answered your question I would greatly appreciate an accepted answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
import ast
a = ['[2,5911,3391,10687,9796,15870,11533]']
ast.literal_eval(a[0])
```

Output:

```
[2, 5911, 3391, 10687, 9796, 15870, 11533]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the standard package `json` for that, in particular the [`loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) method that can deserialize a string:

```
import json

a = ['[2,5911,3391,10687,9796,15870,11533]']

json.loads(a[0])
# [2, 5911, 3391, 10687, 9796, 15870, 11533]
```

Or if you expect `a` to contain more than just one element:

```
a_converted = [json.loads(_el) for _el in a]
# [[2, 5911, 3391, 10687, 9796, 15870, 11533]]
```

The advantage here is that this will work even if the string contains other data types like floats or strings.